# Devise Token Auth - Permanent token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

Is there a way to generate a permanent token with Devise Token Auth, aside from changing the `token_lifespan` setting?

I have an user oriented api that requires login but I also need to set up the same api to be used on integrations, with token authentication

If there's no way to change the token lifespan, any suggestions of how to do this?

Comment: Do you need to do token authentication for the integrations?

Comment: it doesn't necessarily need to be token auth, but it needs to be something permanent

Comment: userid/password auth is "permanent" -- is there a way to leverage that in your integrations? Possibly by adding a token request mechanism.

Comment: I don't think so.. that would require two requests, one to generate the token and the actual request, right? I need it to be a one request thing